# Property record not updating due to routing error patch not discovered although it still exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having this weird error for the action controller where it says that there is a routing error and that the patch does not exist. I checked my routes and there was a patch path for the properties. I also added the patch for the properties in the routes but it still does not update the record instead refreshes the entire page and retrieves the previous data but does not update. It adds a new property record but does not update.

```
class Amenity < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :property, inverse_of: :amenity 
end


class Property < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :amenity, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :property
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :amenity
end


class Admin::PropertiesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_admin!

    def index 
        @properties = Property.all 
    end 

    def new
        @property = Property.new 
        @property.build_amenity 
    end 

    def create
        @property = Property.new(property_params)
        if @property.save 
            redirect_to admin_properties_path, notice: 'Property created successfully'
        else
            render :new
        end 
    end 

    def edit 
        @property = Property.find(params[:id])
        
        puts 'Before editing the value of current property is '  
        puts @property.inspect
        puts @property.amenity.inspect 
    end 

    def update 
        @property = Property.find(params[:id])
        
        puts 'About to update the property values, the current values are '  
        puts @property.inspect
        puts @property.amenity.inspect

        if @property.update(property_params)
            redirect_to admin_property_path(@property), notice: 'Property updated successfully'
            
            puts 'The new property values are '  
            puts @property.inspect
            puts @property.amenity.inspect
        else
            render :edit
            
            puts 'The property update failed '  
            puts @property.inspect  
            puts @property.amenity.inspect
        end 
    end 

    def destroy 
        @property = Property.find(params[:id])
        @property.destroy 
        redirect_to admin_properties_path, notice: 'Property was successfully deleted'
    end 

    private 

    def property_params
        params.require(:property).permit(:title, :name, :owner, :email, :coverage, 
        amenity_attributes: [:id, :has_pool, :has_garage, :has_balcony, :has_roof, :has_terrace, :has_kitchen, :has_storage, :has_barbq, 
        :has_gym, :has_studio, :has_cinema])
    end 
end


Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin, controllers: {
      sessions: 'admin/sessions'
  }
  
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
      sessions: 'users/sessions'
  }
  
  namespace :admin do
    resources :properties 
    patch '/admin/properties/:id', to: 'admin/properties#update', as: 'update' 
  end 


  namespace :users do
    resources :properties 
  end

  root 'pages#home'
  
  get 'pages/users'
  get 'pages/admin'

  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
end

<h1> List of Properties will come here </h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Owner</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @properties.each do |property| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= property.title %></td>
      <td>
        <%= property.owner %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_property_path(property) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= link_to 'Add New Property', new_admin_property_path %>



<%= form_for [:admin, @property], url: admin_properties_path, local: :true do |f| %>

    <h3>Property Details</h3>
    
    <%= f.hidden_field :id %>

    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.label :owner %>
    <%= f.text_field :owner %> 

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>

    <%= f.label :coverage %>
    <%= f.text_field :coverage %> 

    <%= f.fields_for :amenity do |amenity_form| %>
        <%= amenity_form.hidden_field :id %>

        <%= amenity_form.label :has_pool, 'Has Pool?' %>
        <%= amenity_form.check_box :has_pool %> 

        <%= amenity_form.label :has_garage, 'Has Garage?' %>
        <%= amenity_form.check_box :has_garage %> 

        <%= amenity_form.label :has_balcony, 'Has Balcony?' %>
        <%= amenity_form.check_box :has_balcony %> 

        <%= amenity_form.label :has_roof, 'Has Roof?' %>
        <%= amenity_form.check_box :has_roof %> 

        <%= amenity_form.label :has_terrace, 'Has Terrace?' %>
        <%= amenity_form.check_box :has_terrace %>
        
        <%= amenity_form.label :has_kitchen, 'Has Kitchen?' %>
        <%= amenity_form.check_box :has_kitchen %>
        
        <%= amenity_form.label :has_storage, 'Has Storage?' %>
        <%= amenity_form.check_box :has_storage %> 

        <%= amenity_form.label :has_barbq, 'Has Bar BQ?' %>
        <%= amenity_form.check_box :has_barbq %>
        
        <%= amenity_form.label :has_gym, 'Has Gym?' %>
        <%= amenity_form.check_box :has_gym %> 

        <%= amenity_form.label :has_studio, 'Has Studio?' %>
        <%= amenity_form.check_box :has_studio %>
        
        <%= amenity_form.label :has_cinema, 'Has Cinema?' %>
        <%= amenity_form.check_box :has_cinema %> 
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit (property.new_record? ? 'Create Prpoerty' : 'Update Property') %>
<% end %>type here
```

I want to have the property record updated but instead it refreshed and shows the old data

Comment: I updated the form URL to 

<%= form_for [:admin, @property], url: admin_property_path(@property), local: true, method: :patch do |f| %>

That did the trick, now the form is updating data record